# tinytex not finding tabu.sty when downloading PDF for the first time

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, tinytex

I am generating a PDF r markdown document as part of a downloadable report in a shiny application using download handler. I am using the tinytex package.

Once published to RStudio Connect though if I try and download I am getting an error that states that tabu.sty cannot be found and it errors. If though I then download again straight after the PDF is published and downloaded without any issues. Any thoughts as to why this may be happening? The same thing occurs in rstudio but with a different sty file (multirow.sty). I use neither tabu or multirow in my markdown documents.

Comment: Are you referring to *RStudio Connect*?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it has been updated to be clearer.

Comment: Ok. I have removed the `connect` tag since that is meant for a different software product. Questions about RSC aren't very common (yet) on SO. Anyway, can you add a [mre] as well as information about the software versions involved?